# FlatButton dont have any pressing effect / animation

Tags: flutter

Im new to Flutter and the buttons in the following code is not showing any button press effect when I press the buttons. I tried both in simulator as well as on android device too.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: null,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: Text('First Button'),
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: null,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Text('Click Me'),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ],
      )),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onPressed is null  that why you not getting press event

```
 FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: Text('Click Me'),
      ),
```